# Css rule to select children of the same element

Tags: css, css-selectors

How could I more simply write

```
#test div, #test span{
    ....
}
```

is there something like?

```
#test [div span]{
    ....
}
```

(edit: or is it?

```
#test{
    div span{
        ....
    }
 }
```

nope it isn't sorry)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a CSS preprocessor (like LESS, SASS or other) and organize your css in a more structured way, something like

```
#test {
    div  { ... }
    span { ... }
}
```

and, if you're not interested at all at Internet Explorer or Opera support, you could use `:any()` selector like so

```
#test :-moz-any(div, span),
#test :-webkit-any(div, span) {
   ...
}
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3A-moz-any

Another possibility is to apply a specific class to all the nested element you're interested and target those elements via

```
#test .specificclass { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the * selector which would affect all children regardless of their node type.

```
#test * {color: green;}
```

Comment: is there a possibility to filter more what children are affected? or probably the right way is to affect a class to my children,  but thanks your answer is satisfying

Comment: be nice an give it +1 then :)

Comment: ok but it's almost satisfying, it doesn't work with the * because other libraries elements are messed, isn't there a filtering method for css children? or should use class

Comment: `*` is probably the worst you can do... should be -1

Comment: Why is * the worst you can do ?